# vb.net - Functions and Arbitrary typed Generics

Tags: vb.net, generics

Is there a way to create a function/sub signature that accepts an arbitrary typed generic in vb.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its like this:

```
Public Function DoThing(Of T)(ByVal value As T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about generic types in Visual Basic here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx